# File Not Found "Index.html" Redirect To Another Page

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating an app and I keep coming across this problem. The 'Sign-up page' has a "sign in" link to it that is intended to redirect the user to a 'login page/form'. However, when I run the code standalone that is the "index.html" file when I click the 'sign-in' link it says the file is not found. Though, if I use "VS Code's Live Server" that is 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html' it works perfectly fine. Here's the code for the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" />
    <title>Connect Us</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <section class="form signup">
            <header>Connect Us</header>
            <form action="#">
                <div class="error-txt">This is an error message!</div>
                <div class="name-details">
                    <div class="field input">
                        <label>First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="First Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="field input">
                        <label>Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field input">
                    <label>Email Address</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email">
                </div>
                <div class="field input">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a password">
                    <i class="fas fa-eye"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="field input">
                    <label>Confirm Password</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Re-enter the password">
                    <i class="fas fa-eye"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="field image">
                    <label>Profile Picture</label>
                    <input type="file">
                </div>
                <div class="field button">
                    <input type="submit" value="Take me to chat">
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="link">Already connected? <a href="/login.html">Sign In</a></div>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And here is the code for the login.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" />
    <title>Connect Us</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <section class="form login">
            <header>Connect Us</header>
            <form action="#">
                <div class="error-txt">This is an error message!</div>
                <div class="field input">
                    <label>Email Address</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email">
                </div>
                <div class="field input">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your password">
                    <i class="fas fa-eye"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="field button">
                    <input type="submit" value="Take me to chat">
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="link">New Member? <a href="#">Sign Up</a></div>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Clarification to what my problem is:

file:///C:/login.html

Your file couldn’t be accessed
It may have been moved, edited, or deleted.
ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Though when I run the same code with 'VS Code' it works perfectly.

**NOTE**
When I click the 'Sign in' link this http shows instead:

http://127.0.0.1:5500/login.html

Comment: change `<a href="/login.html">Sign In</a>` to `<a href="login.html">Sign In</a>` it will work. It all ties to the way you use your file URI's. It works fine from VS code because when you start from VS Code its runs over your local server on port: 5500 as per your url. The href link with a `/` before is an absolute uri and will fine only when the site is hosted/run on a server.

Comment: As @manish says, the leading slash makes it an absolute url, meaning it’s resolved as a root path. When you’re viewing the file url the root is `file:///C:/`, which isn’t where your project is. When you’re using the web server it works because the server is configured to serve from your project folder, so `/` resolves to the folder where both index and login are.

Answer (score 0):

You have href = /login.html

When you open the file directly, the href starting with a forward slash tells the browser to find login.html in the filesystem root directory. See here http://www.linfo.org/forward_slash.html. login.html probably is in a folder several layers deep, so the browser cannot find it.

If you request the resource through a HTTP server, a forward slash tells the server to find login.html in the document root, where you are likely to store all your website’s files.

I hope my explanation is not too confusing. Please point out any problems.